# Read PPM signal on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi

I have an FS-IA6B, which supports outputting PPM data. The device is a receiver for RC controls (axis inputs, including throttle/pitch/roll/yaw). I was wondering if I could parse the output, which contains 6 channels, into my Raspberry Pi over GPIO, and then display the raw data.

Comment: PPM? Pixmap file format? The device outputs images in the PPM format? Or do you mean "pages per minute"?  Parts per million? What is an PPM signal? Did you read the documentation to your device? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading PWM / PPM requires microsecond precision which might not be easily possible on Raspberry Pi.

The easiest way to capture PPM reliably would be to get a cheap microcontroller with serial or I2C interface and hook it to your Raspberry Pi.

Firstly, you can try understanding how Pulse Position Modulation (PPM) works. PPM is somewhat like PWM, except that it's the time between pulses that carries the data, and not the duration of the pulse itself. [Reference](https://hackaday.io/project/2465-manucon-a-glove-based-controller/log/8254-ppm-output)

[image: PPM Frame]

You can use hardware timed sampling of **pigpio** to calculate the time periods between RISING edges of your PPM frame.

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [hardware interrupt](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/) on an Arduino to calculate the time periods between RISING edges of your PPM frame and send the output to your RaspberryPi over serial or I2C.

Here is a brilliant [article](https://hackaday.io/project/2465-manucon-a-glove-based-controller/log/8254-ppm-output) which could be a good starting point.